# The '*.ldb' files in `~/.ethereum/geth/chaindata`are not sequence one after one, is it normal?

Tags: go-ethereum

I start ethereum with command:

```
 geth --syncmode fast --cache 256
```

and I find my files in `~/.ethereum/geth/chaindata` are like:

```
000390.ldb
000392.ldb
000420.ldb
000484.ldb
```

They are not one after one. And also, the latest file name is `957905.ldb`, but `ls *.ldb | wc -l` shows me only `63067`.

Is it normal? Or is there data missing? Is there any way to check if the data are complete?

Comment: I've checked in my blockchain data files and they also have discontinuity in files numbering. So I'd say it is normal.